# ng-hide is not working in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I need two ng-hide directives.One for editing the salary and one for hiding the salary.But if I use two ng-hide directives in single html tag,only editing works but hiding is not working.

```
<table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td ng-hide="hide"><span>Salary</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="faculty in facultymembers track by $index">
                <td><span ng-hide="editmode">{{faculty.id}}</span>
                <input
                    type="text" ng-show="editmode" ng-model="faculty.id"></td>
                <td><span ng-hide="editmode">{{faculty.name}}</span>
                <input
                    type="text" ng-show="editmode" ng-model="faculty.name"></td>
                <td><span ng-hide="editmode || hide">{{faculty.salary}}</span>
                <input
                    type="text" ng-show="editmode" ng-model="faculty.salary"></td>
                <td><button ng-hide="editmode" ng-click="editmode=true;editfaculty($index)">EDIT</button>
                    <button ng-show="editmode" ng-click="editmode=false">DONE</button></td>
                <td><button ng-click="removefaculty($index)">REMOVE</button></td>
                <td><button ng-hide="hide" ng-click="hide=true">Hide salary</button>
                <button ng-show="hide" ng-click="hide=false">Show salary</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Change ng-hide to ng-show="!editmode"

Comment: Or change `hide-false` to `hide=false`.

Comment: <td><span ng-hide="editmode" ng-hide="hide">{{faculty.salary}}</span>
    <input
     type="text" ng-show="editmode" ng-model="faculty.salary"></td>
    <td><button ng-hide="editmode" ng-click="editmode=true;editfaculty($index)">EDIT</button>
     <button ng-show="editmode" ng-click="editmode=false">DONE</button></td>
    <td><button ng-click="removefaculty($index)">REMOVE</button></td>
    <td><button ng-hide="hide" ng-click="hide=true">Hide salary</button>
    <button ng-show="hide" ng-click="hide-false">Show salary</button></td>
   </tr>

Comment: Still hiding doesn't works properly

Comment: what is the diff between ng-show="editmode" and ng-show="!editmode"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the 2 statements:

```
ng-hide="hide || editmode"
```

Comment: but the data inside the salary only getting hided.So what should I do for hiding the salary coloum itself including table head?

Comment: <td><span ng-hide="hide">Salary</span></td>

Comment: You need to move the `ng-hide` from the `span` to the `td` and `th` elements; that way the columns will not appear at all.

use the same statements for the ng-hide inside `td` and `th`; otherwise you'll get weird results.

Comment: See my edited code.In that I used ng-hide in <td>.But eventhough the salary column is not getting hided only data inside that is getting hided.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? did you add the same `ng-hide="..."` statement to the corresponding `th` element?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `ng-hide` statement in the bottom `tr` is in a `span` tag, not a `td` tag. Is this what you're trying to hide?

Answer (score 1):

Use a logical Or operator `ng-hide="variableA || variableB"` or you could use `ng-show` and negate the condition (`ng-show="!variableB"`), that way you can have a hack to have two `ng-hide`s'

would personally prefer to use logical operators.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the last line in the `ng-click`. 
Yours:

`<button ng-show="hide" ng-click="hide-false">Show salary</button></td>`

Should be:

`<button ng-show="hide" ng-click="hide=false">Show salary</button></td>`

You have a `-` that should be a `=`.